# mod perl configuration not working

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl2

I am trying to execute perl script from virtual host file in apache2 running on Ubuntu.
I am trying to redirect the URL to perl script as show below, but, I am getting forbidden error when I tried http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/somefile.nff
I have set the permissions to perl script as 777. 
Can anyone suggest me what else needs to be done to make perl script run ?
Below is the configurations in 000-default config file

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
ScriptAliasMatch /(.*) /var/www/perl/
PerlModule ModPerl::Registry
  <Location /perl>
    SetHandler perl-script
    PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options ExecCGI
    allow from all
    PerlSendHeader On
  </Location>
```